# Using JQuery 1st Time

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging

I'm referencing it as it says on w3schools and [this](http://reallifejs.com/brainchunks/including-jquery/) website

```
<head>
    <script>
        src = 'C:\path...\jquery-1.11.3.js';

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("p").click(function() {
                $(this).hide();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <p>If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
    <p>Click me away!</p>
    <p>Click me too!</p>
</body>
```

I compile and open on chrome but when I click any of those 3 messages they don't disappear =P

Comment: What are you using to compile the JavaScript?

Comment: I'm using dreamweaver

Answer (score 0):

External scripts are loaded with the `src` attribute, like this

```
<script src='jquery-1.11.3.js'></script>
```

The path to the file should be referenced using paths [relative to the root of your application](http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/), not the map structure of your system.

Answer (score 0):

Put the `src` tag in the `script` tag:

```
<script scr="C:\path...\jquery-1.11.3.js">
```

P.S. Always use double qoutes!

P.P.S.  If you still can't figure it out, go to the console and look for any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Also: prepare to get *very* familiar with the "Developer" tab in your browser ... particularly the "JavaScript console."  When a JS program encounters any sort of error, the browser's usual response is to "simply stop ... *silently."*  And, if there's any sort of syntax-error, to *"silently"* issue a warning or error message to the JavaScript console (which ordinary users never see).

Any of these things can produce the result that you now see, namely:  *"nothing happens."*

It can be *quite* frustrating, really . . .

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the path, not sure if any of the answers above because what I did was copy paste what they had and tried it without my messy code, and it worked. Then I linked the online Jquery library as oppose to linking what I had in the folder and it worked, then I fixed the path I had. Maybe it was the quotes, not sure now. Thanks anyways. (I wasn't getting errors below in the debugger box =P)